# Sandbox a java applet

Tags: mac, virtual-machine, java

I heard that minecraft server is very leaky, can consume a lot of resources very quickly. People say to use a virtual machine, all well and good. I'm making an application to automate server setup, and I'd like my whole application (including minecraft) to run in an ultra basic auto setup vm (or something similar). I've heard of mineos, but I'm not sure if that can be set up very quickly. The vm will be so basic it won't even have a ui. I'm using a Mac, not planning to distribute the server WITH the application but have it download from the minecraft server, not modified.

I want it to be like a one-click-done solution for the end user, they don't have to worry about minecraft server gobbling up resources because it's be in a controllable virtual machine.

Distrubuting minecraft server (Notch's property) could be an issue, but if anyone knows about that if be happy to hear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than writing a program, why not just create the VM, but make snapshots. So rather than recreating the VM, just revert back to a previous snapshot. . .

Comment: Good idea!  I never would have thought of that.

Comment: Glad that helped.